# How to retrieve information about Logic Pro softsynth configuration from LSO file?

Tags: logic

So I haven't made music in a really long time, but I made sure to save all my LSO song files from Logic so that in the future when I do get back to it I can finish unfinished songs, have old songs, etc.

That time has come, and I have Logic Pro X. There is no problem loading the LSOs but the problem comes in that many of the tracks use software synths that are discontinued or don't even work on the latest macOS. Battery 3, Absynth 4, and Kore 2.0 for example (Kore 2.0 being a wrapper like Komplete Kontrol that was discontinued a while ago)

I bought Komplete 13, and have Battery 4 and Absynth 5... but when I load up the songs obviously it says that cannot find "Battery 3", "Absynth 4" etc. I contacted Native Instruments about it and they said it's not possible.. but I know that information is stored somewhere..

Is there any software out there that has deciphered the LSO file, how the information is stored so maybe I can extract what preset was being used, or what sample banks, etc. in Battery 3? I simply refuse to believe there is no way to solve this issue.

Also think it's lame that there's no way for you to "migrate" to a newer version of the plugin. Of course at time of upgrade you can just record the patch info, knob settings etc. and transfer it to the new plugin, so its only a problem if like me, you come back after that many years.

Like a fool I threw away my old Komplete disks thinking there's no way that NI would allow an upgrade (which they still do from Komplete 2.. lol)

but anyway outside of finding an old Macbook Pro and getting Battery 3 and Absynth 4 and Kore 2 is there a way that I can somehow read the information in the LSO file so I can find out patch info, knob settings, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I fully sympathise with your predicament, but that your 'simple' request for something to be able to read out the parameter sets is really not as simple as that.

I'd start by setting up a VM with the last version of macOS that can run those older versions. VMWare Fusion is available free for personal use.
If you can save out the settings as patches, then there is a chance the next version can still not only open that patch, but also make sense of it.
This isn't guaranteed. Opening doesn't mean they'll sound the same, unfortunately.

If you cannot open the patches in newer versions, then even if the VM version limps like a three-legged donkey on a cobbled street, you will at least be able to 'print' the audio stems from each patch/Midi track, then import to your current version.

I don't have experience with all the specific synths you have listed, but I can parallel this to a similar issue I faced some years ago.

Some deep background…
I've been a writer/muso/engineer/producer since the late 70s/early 80s. In the 90s I semi-retired & worked for one of the major multinational musical instrument companies. As such I had contact with all the major software makers of the time - to this day I still have friends at some of them. That, I'm aware, makes me fairly privileged. However…

In the mid 2k's I produced & recorded an album for a record company. Ten years later they wanted to do a full remix & remaster of it.

The original was done on WinXP, using a version of Cubase & plugins that had long gone out of support.
With the assistance of contacts at many of the companies responsible for this huge variety of software, I managed to get the ancient Cubase files & many of the plugins transferred to a modern Mac - using a windows VM initially - & converted to a usable format.

That took care of the songs' "overview" & all the recorded audio. Some of the plugins, however, not only no longer existed, the companies no longer in business, their authorisation servers were gone, so we couldn't re-authorise.  [One of the developers for one plug actually sent me a cracked version of his own software to bypass this;)) Fortunately, many of these were replaceable reverbs & echos, simple time-modulation fx etc, that I could replace by ear with modern versions by other manufacturers.

For many of the plugs I was given authorisation codes that were good for all versions from old to current & access to all those different versions…  but with all the will in the world, we could not get all the plugins to export/import as we went through each subsequent release version.

Some plugins, even having working copies of every version, we could not get back the original sounds. Not only had the file formats changed [which we were usually able to work through even if some took 4 or 5 major incarnations of the plugs to achieve it], but the internal 'wiring' of the virtual sonic components had changed. Even using known-good conversions, the new plugs sounded different to the old ones.

I ended up using a combination of newly converted plugs & some 'printed' stems from the original.
However, we ultimately failed to get everything across & had to recreate some of it from scratch. The record company vowed that in future, part of the organisational backup process for a recording would include cling-filming the computer it was recorded on & storing it with the project. [I don't actually know whether they ever implemented this or what became of the strategy.]

If you ask nicely, I'm certain the manufacturers of each plug will give you access to older versions - but you still need a working VM to run them, to be prepared for a lot of work, and ultimate disappointment.